# Significance test for Pearson Correlation Coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, statistical-significance, matlab

How can I compute the significance test (P value) for the correlation coefficient (r) using R or Matlab? i.e Can anybody help me with the suitable code to compute the p value for the correlation coefficient in R or Matlab?

The output of the calculators available online to compute p value for r is totally different! That's why I am looking for a trusted code to compute it using R or Matlab

Comment: See this link (http://vassarstats.net/textbook/ch4apx.html).

Answer (score 5):

Say 
`r <- cor(x, y)
n<-length(x)`

Two-tailed tests:

1. Testing using Student's t-distribution:

`t<-r*sqrt((n-2)/(1-r^2))
p<-2*pt(-abs(t),n-2)`

2. Using the Fisher transformation

`z<-(atanh(r)-0)*sqrt(n-3)
p<-2*pnorm(-abs(z))`

Answer (score 3):

You an use the cor.test() function in R to get the p-value.

If you look at the code for the function, by using:

```
getAnywhere("cor.test.default")
```

You can see how the p-value is calculated. The important bit is:

```
r <- cor(x, y)
df <- n - 2L
STATISTIC <- c(t = sqrt(df) * r/sqrt(1 - r^2))
p <- pt(STATISTIC, df)
```

Comment: @ Jeremey Miles. Thanks! n is the number of variants! what is L refering to?

Comment: The L forces df to be an integer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014387/whats-the-difference-between-1l-and-1

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/corr.html),

```
[RHO,PVAL] = corr(X,Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, just type

```
cor.test(x,y)$p.value
```

Comment: The p value here is significant if it is less than 0.05?

Comment: If you are testing at the 0.05 level, yes

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use this code (The numbers are an example to show you how to do it):

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(5,6,7,8,9)
cor.test(x,y)
```